# mysql_query check for value range multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check for value range multiple times, this is how i do it till now:

```
<?php
$preischeck = mysql_query("SELECT preis FROM outfits WHERE aktiv = 'ja' and preis <= 100 $marke $farbe");
if(mysql_num_rows($preischeck) > 0) {
     echo "0 - 100 is there";
}
?>
<?php
$preischeck = mysql_query("SELECT preis FROM outfits WHERE aktiv = 'ja' and preis > 100 and preis <= 200 $marke $farbe");
if(mysql_num_rows($preischeck) > 0) {
     echo "100 - 200 is there";
}
?>
```

And so on..
I guess this is too much for the server and there is a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not saying your solution is ideal, but you haven't stated what is wrong with it.  In other words, you are asking 'Any ideas'.  Ideas for what?

Comment: Did you set up your indexes correctly? Simple queries like these should not be too hard for your server.

Comment: The code works correct. I just thought there could be a better code which does the job with only one request

Comment: You should also consider using MySQLi/PDO_MySQL as MySQL is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.x (http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use an `GROUP BY` in your SQL-query:

```
SELECT preis FROM outfits GROUP BY preis
```

If you want 100-blocks

```
SELECT FLOOR(preis / 100) * 100 FROM outfits GROUP BY FLOOR(preis / 100)
```

Then if 0 is in your resultset you know that 0 - 99,99, if 100 in your resultset 100-199,99 is there etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is probably not a good idea, it can also be done using variables:

```
SELECT 
    @range1 AS range1_count,
    @range2 AS range2_count,
    @range3 AS range3_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF(preis <= 10, @range1 := @range1 + 1, 0),
        IF(preis > 10 AND preis <= 100, @range2 := @range2 + 1, 0),
        IF(preis > 100, @range3 := @range3 + 1, 0)
    FROM
        (SELECT @range1 := 0) i1,
        (SELECT @range2 := 0) i2,
        (SELECT @range3 := 0) i3,
        outfits
    WHERE aktiv = 'ja'
) sub1 LIMIT 1;
```